# Opening disc image in Windows Explorer for mounting in Daemon Tools

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

When I open any DT-supported disc image with DT in Windows Explorer, I get an error from DT (Error in command line). Opening from DT-tray right-click menu working normally. How to make it open from Windows Explorer?
I have DT Lite 4.30.4.0027 and Windows 7 Ultimate x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download a later version.

Daemon Tools is now in version 4.35.5, which is said to support x64.

Comment: I have no problem with mounting images through daemon tools tray menu.

Comment: Anyway, upgrading to the newest version solved the problem :-)